# Как отловить событие — добавление бота в беседу в vk api?

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api

Делаю бота для конференции, и возник вопрос, как отловить событие добавление бота в беседу?

В данный момент я получаю от longpoll ответ такого типа:

```
{"ts":"666","updates":[{"type":"message_new","object":{"date":11111111,"from_id":11111111,"id":0,"out":0,"peer_id":2000000001,"text":"текст","conversation_message_id":450,"fwd_messages":[],"important":false,"random_id":0,"attachments":[],"is_hidden":false},"group_id":11111111}]}
```

Далее я уже этот запрос обрабатываю. Логично предположить что если есть тип `"message_new"`, должен быть тип который отвечает за добавление бота в беседу, но я не могу найти что-то похожее на это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть на объект сообщения в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/objects/message), то там есть поле `action - информация о сервисном действии с чатом.`. Это поле приходит **только** при сервисном действии с чатом (обновление фотографии беседы, добавление пользователей, закрепление сообщения и т.д.).

---

Таким образом, при добавлении нового пользователя (или самого бота) приходит ивент с типом события `"message_new"` и в поле `"object"` содержащий поле `"action"`, в котором в поле `"type"` содержится значение `"chat_invite_user"`, **но** бот будет видеть добавление других пользователей в беседу только при полном доступе к переписке беседы (либо в роли администратора беседы).

---

Пример:

```
{
    "ts": "854",
    "updates": [
        {
            "type": "message_new",
            "object": {
                "date": 1566542736,
                "from_id": 666, // id инициатора события (тот, кто пригласил)
                "id": 0,
                "out": 0,
                "peer_id": 2000000004,
                "text": "",
                "conversation_message_id": 5,
                "action": { // Это поле имеется только при служебном действии с беседой
                    "type": "chat_invite_user", // Тип действия
                    "member_id": -555 // id того, кого пригласили (я для проверки добавил самого бота)
                },
                "fwd_messages": [],
                "important": false,
                "random_id": 0,
                "attachments": [],
                "is_hidden": false
            },
            "group_id": 8888
        }
    ]
}
```